# How to modally present a View Controller on tap of tab bar item

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationcontroller, storyboard, uitabbarcontroller

I have created a tab bar view controller with 3 bar item, in storyboard.

Now on tap of a tab bar item I want to present a ViewController which is connected to tab bar item via Navigation controller.

How this can be achieved programmatically since I have not created any tab bar object.

(OR)
Is there a way to capture the tab bar item selection (which is created in storyboard)

Thank You...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this in viewDidLoad: to assign view controllers to each of the buttons:

```
self.tabBarController.viewControllers = 
 @[firstViewController,secondViewController,thirdViewController];
```

Here is how to detect the tap of the button:

```
-(void) tabBarController:(UITabBarController *)tabBarController didSelectViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController
{
    if (tabBarController.selectedIndex == 0) {
       // present your first view controller
    }
    else if (tabBarController.selectedIndex == 1) {
      // present your second view controller
    }
    else if (tabBarController.selectedIndex == 2) {
      // present your third view controller
    }
}
```

Comment: Do i have to write it in AppDelegate inside didFinishLaunching method?

Comment: Do it inside your UITabBarViewController class that loads the tab bar view controller.

Comment: But it is created using storyboard and this is one more tab bar item that has been added to the same .. hence there are no classes created for it...

Answer (score 0):

Use the [**UITabBarControllerDelegate**](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITabBarControllerDelegate_Protocol/#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UITabBarControllerDelegate/tabBarController:didSelectViewController:) to get notified about which tab got selected.